# Streaming data over REST

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, rest, streamingresponsebody

Hello is there any way to read streamed data over REST? I have an application with one microservice. I would like to send request from micreservice to main app and get these data by batch size.
I followed https://jvmaware.com/streaming-json-response/

Spring boot framework

Java 1.8

Main app getting data from database:

```
public Stream<Transaction> getTrx(String id, int batchSize, TrxFilter filter) {
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(batchSize);
        String sql = ...

        log.info("Fetching {} transactions for id: {}", batchSize, id);

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(sql, (ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) -> {
            return new Transaction(resultSet.getLong("id"));
        });
    }
```

Main app API:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getTransactions/{id}/{batchSize}")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getTrx(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("batchSize") int batchSize, @RequestBody TrxFilter filter) {
        Stream<Transaction> trxs = service.getTrx(id, batchSize, filter);
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)))) {
                trxs.forEach(trx -> {
                    try {
                        log.info("WRITING: {}", trx.getId().getSequenceId());
                        writer.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trx));
                        writer.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Exception occurred while writing object to stream.", e);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                log.error("Exception occurred while publishing data.", exception);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        };
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(responseBody);
    }
```

I tried this, but get nothing, what am I doing wrong?

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("http://.../repeng/getTransactions/" + id + "/" + batchSize);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.getOutputStream().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(filter));

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String data;
            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Transaction transaction = objectMapper.readValue(data, Transaction.class);
                log.info("Received transaction {}", transaction);
                transactions.add(transaction);
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there any way to test this? Can Postman work with streaming REST?

thx <3

Comment: Obligatory announcement: Java 8 is 10 years old. Don't accept silently to work on this code base.

Comment: I see suggestions to stop using Java 8, I upvote

Comment: I wanted to migrate to java 17 but our infra cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Some Points:

- The API endpoint should follow the standards. Something like this: /transaction/{id}/{batchSize}
- getTrx method has a parameter *filter*, which maps request body to TrxFilter object. So there must be an input JSON that must be sent in the request body.
- Use Postman to test the REST API endpoints. If you have to change the request, you can easily modify it in Postman and test to see the expected response. Testing the APIs by writing Java code is cumbersome unless if there is any requirement for it.
- Please check if it is really required to call flush() method.
- Can we try something like this?

```
StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream -> {
     trxs.forEach(trx -> {
        outputStream.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trx).getBytes());
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not test the rest using java code. I need to get data from one app to another. For example, there will be 3 milions transactions and i need them to get to the microservice.
Are you sure you can use postman for streaming? About flush I am not sure.

Comment: Not sure about your application architecture/infra. But processing 3 million records need careful planning of setting up optimized data storage, highly scalable and redundant infra. Postman is just for unit/integration testing if your API is working correctly as expected. You might consider sending the data asynchronously by using distributed queues to another service. There could be many ways to achieve this. But need to discuss the trade-offs and see which is the right approach for this use case.

Comment: I will try gRPC
https://www.baeldung.com/java-grpc-streaming